# I need a "BinarySecurityToken" when I call "SOAP Service" using ".Net Core"

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core, ws-security

I want to create something like below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="…#Base64Binary" ValueType="…#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-1776694">
      MIIDDDCCAfSgAwIBAgIQM6YEf7FVYx/tZyEXgVComTANBgkqhkiG9w0SDGBSDJHBK34...
    </wsse:BinarySecurityToken> 
    <ds:Signature>
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /> 
        <ds:Reference URI="#id-1464350">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /> 
          <ds:DigestValue">1JmC1C0FrlPB42xfFKolgaCew5k=</ds:DigestValue> 
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue">
        H1b7jH2bHpbrzJXkFS0msdUYycDMH4n6m4oTRtbo4Yk35/JzGcuwUYZ3...
      </ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-13498124">
          <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-1776694" ValueType="…#X509v3" /> 
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="id-1464350">
  ...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I have the next code:

```
OperationsClient client = new OperationsClient();
var response = await client.MarketInfoAsync(request);

...

internal partial class OperationsClient
{
  static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
  {
    serviceEndpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/");

    (serviceEndpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    (serviceEndpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

    clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, 509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "XXXXX");                                            
  }
}
```

I recieve the error:

> SECU1075: An error was discovered processing the `<`wsse:Security`>` header

I have tried changig this:

```
(serviceEndpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
(serviceEndpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding).Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
```

But in this case I recieve following error:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'testmisapi.ercot.com'.

I have read that I can use *IClientMessageInspector* but I don't know how can I add the complete Security header.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure the WCF client could consume this kind of web service. Both basichttpbinding with transportwithmessagecredential and the custom binding with below configuration can create this type of SOAP message.
Both of the SOAP messages contain a Timestamp markdown.
Please give me feedback. Besides, establishing a trust relationship requires the client to install the server’s certificate to express trust.

Comment: <customBinding>
        <binding name="custombinding">
          <textMessageEncoding></textMessageEncoding>
          <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"  >
          </security>
          <httpsTransport>
          </httpsTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

Comment: How can I create this XML binding in C# code?
I have installed the certificate provided by the server

Comment: TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncodingBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            TransportSecurityBindingElement transportSecurityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement();
            HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransportBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(textMessageEncodingBindingElement, transportSecurityBindingElement, httpsTransportBindingElement);

Comment: Please refer to this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/securitybindingelement-authentication-modes

Comment: I don't have "CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement", do I need a specific nuget package?

Comment: WCF client using message layer security is not supported in DotNet Core.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2766
Even in the DotNet framework. I am not sure if it works.

Comment: Thanks, so I suppose this is impossible currently.